# PowerSchool API Specification

Tags: php, powerschool

A github project, PowerAPI, offers a PHP library for fetching information from PowerSchool SISes, but this does not appear to have originated from PowerSchool. Is API documentation available from some official source?

Answer (score 3):

The newest link to PowerSchool API documentation is https://support.powerschool.com/article/66558.

Please note, as Chris mentioned in the previous comment, that you will need a PowerSource account to login in and access this information.

**UPDATE:** PowerSchool API Documentation can now be found at [support.powerschool.com/developer/#/page/home](https://support.powerschool.com/developer/#/page/home)

Comment: PowerSchool API Documentation can now be found at https://support.powerschool.com/developer/#/page/home -- PowerSchool account needed to access page.

Answer (score 2):

Updated information about the PowerSchool API (Release verison 1.4) is available on the PowerSource.  (https://powersource.pearsonschoolsystems.com/dir/7536?from=search).
You need a powersource account to login to the support site.